# Django: ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit

Tags: python, django

I am getting `ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit` in my Django app. If I remove haystack from install apps, it goes away. I have tried upgrading haystack, downgrading haystack, removing all the code associated with haystack but it is still an issue.

Full traceback:

```
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/pyProjects/projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/pyProjects/projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/user/pyProjects/projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/user/pyProjects/projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/user/pyProjects/projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/user/pyProjects/projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    maxnofile[1]))
ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit
```

installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # 3rd Party Modules
    'corsheaders',
    'crispy_forms',
    'rest_framework',
    'wkhtmltopdf',
    'autocomplete_light',
    'whoosh',
    'haystack',
    'threadedcomments',
    'django_comments',
    'pytz',
)
```

Comment: what database configuration are you using?

Comment: `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}`

Comment: Are you running on a Mac OS?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yea I am

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you did

`pip install haystack`

However, you should use django-haystack, so do

`pip uninstall haysatck`

`pip install django-haystack`