# Python + Django debug startup on WSGI

Tags: django, macos, python-3.x, wsgi, gunicorn

I'm facing a crash launching with GUNICORN my App on MacOsX Sierra.

Is there any way to better understand the error message? Like to know which dependency is missing or something like that?

I searched online for more log-level info but, right now, the error is not easy to understand.

I report the error if somebody has any clue or any tool to drill down the exception and find it out!

I believe you did

I Already tried this solution and django-haystack was already there

```
pip install haystack
pip uninstall haysatck
pip install django-haystack
```

Thanks in advance

```
gunicorn direttoo.wsgi:application --workers 1 --bind 127.0.0.1:8001 --log-level Info
[2017-03-24 12:30:51 +0100] [3304] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-03-24 12:30:51 +0100] [3304] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8001 (3304)
[2017-03-24 12:30:51 +0100] [3304] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-03-24 12:30:51 +0100] [3307] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3307
[2017-03-24 11:30:51 +0000] [3307] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
worker.init_process()
 File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
self.load_wsgi()
 File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
 File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
self.callable = self.load()
 File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
__import__(module)
File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/direttoo/wsgi.py", line 36, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup()
File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Users/diegobanovaz/Projects/direttoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
maxnofile[1]))
ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit
[2017-03-24 11:30:51 +0000] [3307] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3307)
[2017-03-24 12:30:51 +0100] [3304] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-03-24 12:30:51 +0100] [3304] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502656/django-valueerror-current-limit-exceeds-maximum-limit)

Comment: @AlexPavlenko the other solution is not working